# Screen resolution 1024px or 960px?

Tags: web, grid, size, system, standards

Back in the day we use to design website with resolution:

```
1024px(width) by 768px(height)
```

but to avoid getting scrollbar from appearing from both sides we use a slightly smaller resolution, may be:

```
1000px(width) by 620px(height)---rectify me if I'm wrong on this one
```

but my main concern is how did 960 grid system comes to place? I know it is good for laying out contents accordingly within the 960px grid, but if so why not just use 1000px instead? Since it is mostly use size during that time?

Comment: I can only guess. A 20px margin on both sides, plus 24px for a scrollbar?

Answer (score 2):

The reasoning is like this:

`1024 x 768` was a common resolution at which designs were aimed.

Subtract `24px` for the scroll bar - `1000px`;

`960px` leaves additional breathing room and importantly - has many more factors (division) than `1000px`. `960` is therefore the ideal choice for a grid system.

Here are the factors:

**960**

> 1  2  3  4  5  6  8  10  12  15  16  20  24  30  32  40  48  60  64 
>   80  96  120  160  192  240  320  480  960

**1000**

> 1  2  4  5  8  10  20  25  40  50  100  125  200  250  500  1000

Credit to the answers on this post: [Why width 960px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415758/why-width-960px)